# Vuetify: custom footer for Autocomplete component

Tags: css, vue.js, css-position, vuetify.js, sticky

I need to add some bottom-fixed element to a v-autocomplete component's list using Vuetify, like this:

[image: lower content]

I've tried using the **append-item** slot and applying position: sticky to it, so that it sticks to the bottom while the user scrolls the autocomplete list. This, however, won't work for IE11 (which I need to):

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

I won't be able to add any polyfill for this to my project, so I tried finding another alternative. So far, I've used the v-menu component to attach both the autocommplete and the menu to the same div:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <v-menu content-class="menu" :attach="'.text-center'">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-autocomplete
                :attach="'.text-center'"
                class="autocomplete"
                :items="['something', 'something2']"
                color="primary"
                v-on="on"
                dark
            >
                Dropdown
            </v-autocomplete>
        </template>
        <div class="lower">
            Lower content
        </div>
    </v-menu>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/codepenas/pen/YzXpMYY

It seems to work fine when you first focus on the autocomplete component. However, after clicking on it again, the menu holding the lower content gets deactivated. Moreover, when clicking on the rightest part of the autocomplete, only the list holding the autocomplete's items will be shown.

I need the lower content to toggle when the Autocomplete's list does so, or any other alternative for adding this fixed bottom part.

Comment: What do you want to do with the lower content? What do you expect to append when the user clicks on it? How do you want the item to be fixed? As it is the last item of the list or do you want it always to be displayed when the user scrolls?

Comment: @djcaesar9114 When the user clicks on it, he will be redirected to another site.I want the lower content not to be the last item of the list. Intsead, I need it to be appended outside of the list, so that the user can scroll said list and the lower content is always displayed.

Comment: The lower content should only be displayed as long as the list itself is displayed

Comment: And do you want it to be selectable, like the other ones?

Comment: @djcaesar9114 No, I do not want it to be selectable. I need to be able to put any kind of content there. The only relationship between the lower content and the list is that they need to be shown and hidden together. Thank you

Comment: OK, but if you have a long list, do you want the "lower content" to be shown even if you are not at the end of the list?

Comment: @djcaesar9114 yes, I need it to be shown whenever the list is open, regardless of the list's length and regardless of if im at the end of the list or not. This lower element should be outside of the list, but bound to its open/hide toggling

Answer (score 1):

You can use the item slot, looks ugly but does work, even on IE11:

```
<v-autocomplete 
  :items="[{ value: 'something' }, { value: 'something2' }, 'Lower content']"
>
  <template v-slot:item="data">
    <template v-if="typeof data.item === 'object'">
      <v-list-item-content v-text="data.item.value"></v-list-item-content>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <v-list-item-content v-text="data.item" class="red"></v-list-item-content>
    </template>
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've mentioned in my question that I've already tried that, which includes the element **inside** the menu list. However, I need it to be appended **outside**.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I'v change the answer, I promise it can work for IE11. About the problem of inside or outside , maybe you could make it look like outside by CSS.

Comment: I know it works on IE11. What doesn't work is the sticky css property

Comment: The main problem is making it to be outside

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-menu content-class="menu" :attach="'.text-center'">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-autocomplete
              :attach="'.text-center'"
              class="autocomplete"
              :items="['something', 'something2']"
              color="primary"
              v-on="on"
              dark
            >
              <v-list-item
                slot="append-item"
                class="grey--text">
                {{ items.length }} elements
              </v-list-item>
            </v-autocomplete>
          </template>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working for me. The lower content is not visible when the number of items increase. The lower content is just being inserted as the last item of the list, not outside of it